# sam build is stuck, not able to install library

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

After writing the lambda function and creating the API, I want to run my lambda function in local. for this I use sam build. But sam build is not able to install libraries from requirements.txt file. It will stuck in between.

When I installed library from terminal it will run using `pip install python-jose --no-cache-dir`. but in sam `build --no-cache-dir` is not working.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error, whenever I run "sam build" it will start running and stuck. not move further. 
According to me the problem is, sam build install the dependencies from requirements.txt . I am using python-jose library. so it need "six" library to install. When I install on my terminal using pip, I use pip install python-jose --no-cache-dir. I also fix this but not working in sam build

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this? I'm also getting the same. It got hanged.